# Passing props.children from a container component to a presentational component

Tags: reactjs, routes, children, react-props

I'm doing some routing, I want to try to display `IndexZoomOverviewContainer into IndexZoomViewPanelContainer`.

When I go to the right path **"...index/overview"**, `IndexZoomViewPanelContainer` is displayed, but when I'm passing the children (the Route for `IndexZoomOverviewContainer` in this case) from the container (`IndexZoomViewPanelContainer`) to the view (`IndexZoomViewPanelComponent`), it doesn't display it and gives me an error:

Error ScreenShot : https://i.gyazo.com/990f92d3058806baa576dca5247ace9e.png

When I removed `this.props.children`, its not showing any error.

Here is the routing:

```
<Route className="fullHeight fullWidth" key="indexzoom" path="index/" component={indexmonitor.IndexZoomViewPanelContainer} >
     <Route className="fullHeight fullWidth" key="indexzoom1" path="overview" component={indexmonitor.IndexZoomOverviewContainer} />
     <Route className="fullHeight fullWidth" key="indexzoom2" path={routes.INDEX_ZOOM_CONSTITUENTS_RELATIVE_PATH} component={dashboard.DashboardListContainer} />
 </Route>
```

IndexZoomViewPanelContainer:

```
class IndexZoomViewPanelContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
    }

    render() {
        return <IndexZoomViewPanelComponent>
                  {this.props.children}
               </IndexZoomViewPanelComponent>;
    }
}
```

IndexZoomViewPanelComponent:

```
function IndexZoomViewPanelComponent(props) {
        const tabs = getTabs();
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <viewPanel.ViewPanel title={"Index Zoom"}
                    authKey={perm.INDEX_ZOOM_VIEWPANEL_PERM}
                    path={route.APP_PATH}
                    getPermStateFunc={(state) => state.MENUPERMS}
                >
                    <TabControl tabs={tabs} selected={route.INDEX_ZOOM_OVERVIEW_RELATIVE_PATH}>
                        {props.children}
                    </TabControl>
                </viewPanel.ViewPanel>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to use children specific property?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to try to display **IndexZoomOverviewContainer** into **IndexZoomViewPanelContainer**

```
<Route className="fullHeight fullWidth" key="indexzoom" path="index/" 
component={indexmonitor.IndexZoomViewPanelContainer} >
```

`IndexZoomViewPanelContainer` renderd as a part of routing and it don't have any children

So,

```
return <IndexZoomViewPanelComponent>{this.props.children}</IndexZoomViewPanelComponent>
```

in the above script, `this.props.children` will be undefined and it will throw the error that you have shared.

In order to work this,it should be,

```
 return <IndexZoomViewPanelComponent><IndexZoomOverviewContainer /></IndexZoomViewPanelComponent>
```

Comment: this.props.children actually isn't undefined, when I console.log it in IndexZoomViewPanelContainer : https://i.gyazo.com/11b6bd2e664b76027698f36b06e2c7ac.png . I can't do what you said because I don't want to display the OverviewComponent everytime, I want to do routing and display the right component.

Comment: @amaurygl as you can see in screenshot,its not a valid react element thats what error said.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve what you need in the route :

```
// I'm renaming your components and removing className/key for readability

<Route path="/index" render={() => (
  <IndexZoomViewPanelContainer>
    <Route path="/index/overview" component={IndexZoomOverviewContainer} />
  </IndexZoomViewPanelContainer>
  )}
/>
```

You can also make your nested routes in `IndexZoomViewPanelContainer` component directly.

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func for more infos.